# updating and compacting sqlite database in android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am a bit new to android and I am working on a project which used to have 40 MBs of sqlite database.
Now I wanna put blob data of sqlite in raw folder, so my database is now less than 1 MB.
 The problem is that in the database path(data/data/package name/databases) the db file size is still the same as the past(my cellphone is rooted so I can check it after each debugging).
In DB browser we can use compact database in order to reduce the db size after dropping some tables. now what can I do ?
any help would be appreciated.
tnx in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your question can you simplify it and ask

Comment: @war_Hero . tnx for your attention. I edited my post if u didnot get it again, plz let me know I will try to explain it

Comment: actually I have deleted 1 table of sqlite database and transformed its data to raw folder now the db size that has been copied to cellphone is still the same. You know I want to update my app and in this update I have deleted this table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **`VACUUM`** command may be what you want.

This will copy the data to a temporary database and then use this to overwrite the original.

You would use something along the lines of:-

```
    db.execSQL("VACUUM");
```

Note the warnings about compatibility in the following:-

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - VACUUM](https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html)