# How to use sqlite VACUUM in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an android app which involves login to the app and it performs many CRUD operations. When user logins first time, it logs him/her quickly if there is any data available for that user that will be downloaded. 
But later on when re-login again, theprocess is very slow, sometimes it takes around 20 to 30mins. So, I read about using VACUUM to avoid free space created when the record is deleted.

I am bit confused when and how to use VACUUM, is it while opening the database that is when user login ? or some other time.

Any suggestions on this would be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From: https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html

> Running VACUUM ensures that each table and index is largely stored
>   contiguously 
>  within the database file

About *many CRUD operations*: the db file usually becomes fragmented, 
especially
when these operations involve say deleting large amount of data. 
With Java code it's fairly simple:

```
db.execSQL("VACUUM");
```

although the process can take a while and it is not possible to monitor its progress. 
Of course **you don't need to execute this statement every time you run the app**, but periodically. 
Or you may let the user execute this process, if he/she experiences delays on loading the data, or even logging in, after you make clear that such an operation, just like any reconstructing operation is not 100% safe, so propose first a backup.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. So, when I execute this command it does take some time to complete it. So, is it possible I make an option and allow user to run, but the app slows down.

Comment: *it does take some time to complete* not always. It depends on the size and the fragmentation of the db. Yes you may have say a menu option that the user can click and perform this operation. You could execute this operation in an asynctask, so to present a progressbar for the duration of time the operation is executed.

Comment: Thats great. Thanks for your suggestion. I have one more doubt like according to document it creates temporary database file and later it overwrites the original database file. So do I need to create this temporary database file or need to give any reference to original database file. 
2. Before performing this operation do I need to open database and not start the transaction like adding or deleting data?

Comment: You don;t have to create any temp databases. If any, are taken care of by sqlite engine. Before performing this operation you need to obtain a valid `SQLiteOpenHelper` object, like `db` to use it for the `execSql()` method, just like you need such an object for the CRUD operations. Of course, while the operation is active, you should not try to perform any other operation. After it is finished, it's better (I think) to close and reobtain the `db` object (I did not find this documented). Of course always backup first.

Comment: Great!; I added: db.execSQL("VACUUM") inside a delete function, no errors no problems, now im curious to know how to how know if my database is "vacuumed", does ID primary key reestarts in 1 again?

Comment: The only thing about this that is mentioned in the documentation that you can find here: https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html is: "The VACUUM command may change the ROWIDs of entries in any tables that do not have an explicit INTEGER PRIMARY KEY." So no, if you have defined the id as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`, the new id will start from the last id ever entered in the table +1.